# Join groups of N lines

Tags: vim

I have a text file generated from an old database that consists of one line per field, with no delimiter between records other than knowing how many fields there are.  What I'd like to do is join the first N lines, and then the next N, and so on.  Is there any way to do this within Vim?  Is there were a way to select lines to apply a command to based on an arbitrary VimL expression (like `line(".")%5==0`) instead of just a regex?

Comment: Do you need any special delimiter, or the join by space is enough?

Comment: Join by space is enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple ways of solving this. First that comes to my mind is recording a macro, say in register `w`:

```
qw5Jjq
```

This essentially uses the `J` normal command to join 5 lines and moves one down. Then you can repeat the macro for 20 times with a simple `20@w` or keep repeating afterwards with `@@`.

Another, maybe more "proper" way is using the `:join` ex command, which is the same as the `J` normal command, but can be abbreviated to `:j` and used in conjunction with the `:g` to operate in various lines. For example:

```
:g/./j5
```

This will match every line non-empty line and in each one of them, join the next 5 lines (inclusive). Then move to the next line and join more 5 and so on.

Comment: I totally forgot that the ex-line `join` command took an argument for the number of lines to join.  So `:%j5` works, but I should also have realized that I could just do `:%normal 5J`.  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Of course, you see, your answer is much better than mine, I will edit the `:g` part out for future reference, and thanks for pointing out it, I totally missed it

Comment: @MarkReed could you join multiple times with `:%j5`? I think it will only do the first set of the given range

Comment: you're right, you need the `g/`.  But not `g//`, which repeats the previous regex.  Something like `g/./` to match every (non-empty) line.

Comment: @MarkReed Updated, perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with two simple regex:

```
:%s/\(\(^.*\n\)\{5}\)/\1\r/g
```

This one just put a `return` every 5 line, followed by:

```
:%s/\(\n\{2}\)\|\n/\1/g
```

OR

```
:%s/\n\{2}\zs\|\n//g
```

This removes just 1 `return` character not 2 consecutive ones